# counting the real zeros of a polynomial and proving that it's irreducible over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let's consider the polynomial  $$
f\left( x \right) = \left( {x^2  + 2} \right)\prod\limits_{i =  - k}^k {\left( {x - 2i} \right) + 2 \in {\Bbb Q}\left[ x \right]} 
$$ . Let's suppose that $
p = 2k + 3 \geqslant 5
$ is prime.

Prove the following:

$i)$ Prove that $f$ is irreducible and of degree $p$

$ii)$ Prove that p has exactly $p-2$ real zeros.
I have no idea how to prove this, maybe with einsenstein and considering the derivate, but how? :/

Comment: Can you prove that $f$ has degree $p$?

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $2$, $f(x)$ is just $x^p$; also, the constant term of $f(x)$ is 2; thus, you can apply Eisenstein with $p=2$.

Comment: Ok , and how can I prove that has exactly p-2 real zeros?

Comment: Maybe you can show it changes sign between $n-(1/2)$ and $n+(1/2)$ for $n=-k,\dots,k$.

Comment: Well It's easy to see the following relation, let's call the polynomial $ f_k $ so we can deduce the following $$
f_k  = \left( {f_{k - 1}  - 2} \right)\left( {x - 2k} \right)\left( {x + 2k} \right) + 2
$$
so derivating $ f'_k = f'_{k-1} (x-2k)(x+2k) $ so, in each step I add two more critical points, and clearly $ f'_1 = (x^2-2)(5x^2+4) $  thus $ f'_k$ has exactly $2k$ critical points

Comment: Not sure I follow your differentiation --- was expecting the Product Rule to make an appearance.

Comment: My derivate is bad